# Extending Repeater (or other widget with nested XML tag attributes)

Tags: nativescript

I try extend Repeater. Just do so:

```
// views/widgets/MyRepeater/MyRepeater.ts
import {Repeater} from "tns-core-modules/ui/repeater";

export class MyRepeater extends Repeater {}
```

Now I try use it:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
      xmlns:Test="views/widgets/MyRepeater/MyRepeater">
    <Test:MyRepeater items="{{ items }}">
        <Test:MyRepeater.itemsLayout>
            <StackLayout/>
        </Test:MyRepeater.itemsLayout>
        <Test:MyRepeater.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ someBindingValue }}"></Label>
        </Test:MyRepeater.itemTemplate>
    </Test:MyRepeater>
</Page>
```

It don't produce any errors until first change of `<ObservableArray>items`.
I get such error:

```
JS: TypeError: Cannot set property 'bindingContext' of undefined
JS:     at MyRepeater.Repeater.refresh (file:///data/data/com.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js:48:38)
JS:     at MyRepeater.Repeater._requestRefresh (file:///data/data/com.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js:34:18)
JS:     at MyRepeater.Repeater._onItemsChanged (file:///data/data/com.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js:54:14)
JS:     at Object.handler [as callback] (file:///data/data/com.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/weak-event-listener/weak-event-listener.js:30:34)
JS:     at Observable.notify (file:///data/data/com.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js:110:23)
JS:     at ObservableArray.splice (file:///data/data/com.test/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable-array/observable-array.js:129:14)
```

Look's like in code `tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js:48:38` it tries parse `itemTemplate`, but can't do that.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-export all from `tns-core-modules/ui/repeater` like so:

`export * from 'tns-core-modules/ui/repeater'`

Answer (score 0):

I think your custom repeater file should export the `knownTemplates` module as done in the [original implementation](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.ts#L12-L14) that helps the XML parser to identify the template.

```
export module knownTemplates {
    export const itemTemplate = "itemTemplate";
}
```